# uniquess of hyperbolic numbers

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, split-complex-numbers

> I'm trying to prove, the uniqueness of hyperbolic numbers, like the complex numbers are unique, but since hyperbolic numbers aren't a field, I can't use the ideas of this. Are there theorems of uniqueness of factor groups? 
>   Since (Hyperbolic numbers)  $\mathbb{D} \cong \mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2-1\rangle$

Comment: When one proves that something is unique, one proves that that something is the only object which satisfies such and such properties. What properties do you think that characterize uniquely the ring of hyperbolic numbers?

Comment: In other words, «proving that the hyperbolic numbers are unique» does not make sense without making explicit with respect to what you want uniqueness.

Comment: the fact that $j^2=1$, $1 \ne j \ne -1$

Comment: There are many rings with an element which is not $1$ nor $-1$ which squares to $1$; for example, the direct product of your $\mathbb D$ with **any** other ring.

Comment: The tag (hyperbolic-geometry) is not appropriate. Perhaps just (abstract-algebra) or (commutative-algebra) would be better.